UnimplementedError tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error when try to predict using deep learning model
I have trained my deep learning model and saved it with the name "try_model_in_out.h5", then I want to try to create a website that can receive input and use the model I have trained to predict the results. When I try, it gives me an error like:
enter image description here
I do not know why. I'm still a beginner. This is my structure file:
enter image description here
api.py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import tensorflow as tf
import os
def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
clear()

# Load the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./try_model_in_out.h5")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def mainFunction():
    # Retrieve form data
    haematocrit = float(request.form['haematocrit'])
    haemoglobins = float(request.form['haemoglobins'])
    erythrocyte = float(request.form['erythrocyte'])
    leucocyte = float(request.form['leucocyte'])
    thrombocyte = float(request.form['thrombocyte'])
    mch = float(request.form['mch'])
    mchc = float(request.form['mchc'])
    mcv = float(request.form['mcv'])
    age = float(request.form['age'])
    sex = request.form['sex']
    
    # Make prediction
    features = [[haematocrit, haemoglobins, erythrocyte, leucocyte, thrombocyte, mch, mchc, mcv, age, sex]]
    prediction = model.predict(features)    
    result = "IN" if prediction[0][0] > 0.5 else "OUT"

    return render_template('index.html', haematocrit=haematocrit, haemoglobins=haemoglobins, erythrocyte=erythrocyte, leucocyte=leucocyte, thrombocyte=thrombocyte, mch=mch, mchc=mchc, mcv=mcv, age=age, sex=sex, prediction=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear()
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
    clear()


templates/index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Try Flask</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
    <div class="min-h-[50vh] bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md w-[60%] border-0 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold my-4">Patient Information Form</h1>

        <form class="border-0 w-full my-5" action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="haematocrit" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Haematocrit</label>
                <input type="text" id="haematocrit" value="35.1" name="haematocrit" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="haemoglobins" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Haemoglobins</label>
                <input type="text" id="haemoglobins" value="11.8" name="haemoglobins" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="erythrocyte" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Erythrocyte</label>
                <input type="text" id="erythrocyte" value="4.65" name="erythrocyte" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="leucocyte" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Leucocyte</label>
                <input type="text" id="leucocyte" value="6.3" name="leucocyte" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="thrombocyte" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Thrombocyte</label>
                <input type="text" id="thrombocyte" value="310" name="thrombocyte" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="mch" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">MCH</label>
                <input type="text" id="mch" value="25.4" name="mch" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="mchc" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">MCHC</label>
                <input type="text" id="mchc" value="33.6" name="mchc" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="mcv" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">MCV</label>
                <input type="text" id="mcv" value="75.5" name="mcv" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="age" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Age</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" value="1" name="age" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="sex" class="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-2">Sex</label>
                <select id="sex" value="F" name="sex" class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400">
                    <option value="1">Male</option>
                    <option value="0">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600 w-full">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
        <h1>Prediction Result</h1>
        <p>Haematocrit: {{ haematocrit }}</p>
        <p>Haemoglobins: {{ haemoglobins }}</p>
        <p>Erythrocyte: {{ erythrocyte }}</p>
        <p>Leucocyte: {{ leucocyte }}</p>
        <p>Thrombocyte: {{ thrombocyte }}</p>
        <p>MCH: {{ mch }}</p>
        <p>MCHC: {{ mchc }}</p>
        <p>MCV: {{ mcv }}</p>
        <p>Age: {{ age }}</p>
        <p>Sex: {{ sex }}</p>
        <p>The prediction result is: {{ prediction }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


When I remove this line of code:
api.py
prediction = model.predict(features)    
result = "IN" if prediction[0][0] > 0.5 else "OUT"

To indicate whether the value of the input exists or not, it turns out it does.
enter image description here
I want the prediction results to be displayed too.

You need to post the full error traceback (as code, not an image).
